# IIS Re-write replacing two dashes with /

Tags: url, iis, rewriting

I am trying to make a URL re-write that will change this URL:

http://domain.com/us--texas--austin--article-category--article-name

to

http://domain.com/us/texas/austin/article-category/article-name

So I want to replace every -- (2 dashes) with "/"

What would the web.config look like?

```
<rule name="URL3" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)--([_0-9a-z-]+)--([_0-9a-z-]+)--([_0-9a-z-]+)" ignoreCase="true" /> 
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}" redirectType="Temporary" />

</rule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <rule name="URL3" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)--([_0-9a-z-]+)--([_0-9a-z-]+)--([_0-9a-z-]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>

Comment: Just want to change the 2 dashes to a slash, not working

Comment: Can you update the question to include that config?

Answer (score 0):

Since your url path can be of variable length and contain many instances of double dashes it's better to use rewrite providers rather than trying to match against set number of occurrences. Have a look at [this example](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module) as it covers a case very similar to what you need.